# Call another method onSuccess event of an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have an AJAX call on MVC3 it looks like this

```
save: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Save")",
            type:"post",
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: function(result){alert(result.message)}
        });
    }
```

The trouble is the line

```
success: function(result){alert(result.message)}
```

I want to pass all the messing things in a HtmlHelper, however, the success line prevents me from doing so, is there a way I can specify a function for that line

```
success: doSomeStuff(result)
```

and

```
function doSomeStuff(result){alert(result.message)}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about using the anonymous function to call a named function?

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass the function name to the `success`: method and it will pass the data onwards, as such:

```
save: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Save")",
            type:"post",
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: doSomeStuff
        });
    }
```